# Child Theme not showing as template for Posts in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have created a child theme and am trying to use this on posts.

I can see this child theme inside the `Page Attributes > Template` when on the **Page** settings. But I cannot see this setting on the **Post** settings.

[image]

## Post Page

[image]
[image]

I know that the child theme is working correctly as I can use it without any problems inside the **Page**. It is only the posts I am having a problem with.

Comment: Interesting this was downvoted, please could I get a reason why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom page templates are by default only available to the `page` post type. You need to define the post types (WP 4.7+) your template supports in the template header.

E.g.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Full-width layout
Template Post Type: post, page, event
*/
// Page code here...
```

Source, https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-page-templates-for-specific-post-types